# O que é e como funciona a função PHAR do PHP?

Tags: php

Alguém possui informações sobre a função `phar`?

O que é, para que serve, como utilizar e qual a vantagem?

Achei muita coisa na internet, mas nada tão especifico, então resolvi perguntar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A classe `Phar`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.phar.php) é utilizada para empacotar aplicações PHP em um único arquivo que pode ser facilmente distribuído e executado. Esse nome vem de *PHP Archive* e teve como inspiração os arquivos *jar* (Java Archive) já conhecidos com quem trabalha com Java.

Ele também pode ser utiliza para manipular arquivos compactados em `zip` ou `tar` a partir da [classe `PharData`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.phardata.php), abstraindo seus métodos de forma parecida que o `PDO` faz com os bancos de dados.

Um caso bem comum de uso do `Phar` é o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), uma ferramenta usada para gerenciamento de pacotes em PHP. No seu código fonte temos uma classe chamada [`Compiler`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.4/src/Composer/Compiler.php) que utiliza o `Phar` para gerar o pacote que é distribuído via download para os usuários.

Abaixo separei alguns trechos de código do `Compiler` do Composer que utilizam o `Phar`

```
// Cria um novo arquivo phar
$phar = new \Phar($pharFile, 0, 'composer.phar');

// Abre o resource para receber os arquivos
$phar->startBuffering();

// O Compiler tem esse método addFile, que passa um arquivo e a
// classe Phar
$this->addFile($phar, $file);

// Dentro do addFile, ele tem algumas funções para minificar o código do
// Composer, tirando espaços em branco do $file
// Em seguinda, depois de limpar o arquivo, ele executa um método do phar
// que cria um arquivo no mesmo path minificado
$phar->addFromString($path, $content);

// Esse setStub seria o script que executa sua aplicação, o runner principal
$phar->setStub($this->getStub());

// E pra fechar o arquivo, chamamos o método abaixo
$phar->stopBuffering();
```

Podemos ter mais informações sobre o `Phar` na documentação do PHP (em inglês):

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.phar.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/phar.using.intro.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/phar.fileformat.stub.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.signature.php